# Ввод строк символами в двумерный вектор

Tags: c++

Имеется `vector<vector<char>>` и файл с текстом. Цель: ввод этого текста в двумерный вектор.Как можно это реализовать?
Благодарю,разобрался

Comment: Изобрази пример на пальцах

Comment: Надеюсь, у вас vector<string>, а не vector<vector<char>>? Считали символ - внесли в строку. Повторять до символа конца строки, его игнорировать и переходить на следующий элемент вектора...

Comment: Как раз-таки нужно в  vector<vector<char>>

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что ТС уже разобрался.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что в этой ситуации лучше использовать "одномерный" вектор строк вместо "двумерного" вектора символов.

Например,

```
std::vector<std::string> v;

//...

std::string record;

while ( std::getline( file, record ) ) v.push_back( record );
```

Если же использовать "двумерный" символьный вектор, то решение может выглядеть как

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> v;

//...

std::string record;

while ( std::getline( file, record ) ) v.push_back( { record.begin(), record.end() } );
```

Comment: Ошибка (активно)  отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [с _Ty=std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>, _Alloc=std::allocator<std::vector<char, std::allocator<char>>>]", соответствующие списку аргументов

Comment: @OMedia Возможно, ваш компилятор не поддерживает задание параметров в виде списка в фигурных скобках. Тогда можете написать v.push_back( std::vector<char>( record.begin(), record.end() ) );

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<vector<char>> vl;
    string s;

    while(getline(cin,s))
        vl.push_back({s.begin(),s.end()});

    for(auto v: vl)
    {
        for(auto c: v) cout << c;
        cout << endl;
    }

}
```

См. http://ideone.com/vct4xq

Вместо `cin` можно открыть нужный файл и использовать его:

```
    vector<vector<char>> vl;
    string s;
    ifstream in("filename");
    while(getline(in,s))
```